# Trying to save and get id of document to save ref to another document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm saving form data to a NodeJS API, then getting the ID and saving that ID to another document. The form at this point is actually saving the data to my MLab database but then sending a SERVER 500 error and not getting to my console.logs for me to troubleshoot. Not sure what's happening as the process is pretty simple.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Project = require('../../models/project.model');
const Client = require('../../models/client.model');


router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {

    let clientId = req.body.clientId;

    let newProject = new Project({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        projectTitle: req.body.projectTitle,
        network: req.body.network,
        postSupervisor: {
            name: req.body.postSupervisor.name,
            email: req.body.postSupervisor.email ? req.body.postSupervisor.email : '',
            phone: req.body.postSupervisor.phone ? req.body.postSupervisor.phone : ''
        },
        seriesInformation: {
            services: req.body.seriesInformation.services,
            season: req.body.seriesInformation.season,
            numEps: req.body.seriesInformation.numEps,
            runtime: req.body.seriesInformation.runtime
        },
        technicalDetails: {
            frameRate: req.body.technicalDetails.frameRate,
            videoFormat: req.body.technicalDetails.videoFormat,
            videoFinishing: req.body.technicalDetails.videoFinishing,
            soundFormat: req.body.technicalDetails.soundFormat,
            sampleRate: req.body.technicalDetails.sampleRate,
            bitDepth: req.body.technicalDetails.bitDepth,
            audioLoudness: req.body.technicalDetails.audioLoudness,
            audioAlgorithm: req.body.technicalDetails.audioAlgorithm,
            audioPeakLimit: req.body.technicalDetails.audioPeakLimit,
            technicalSpec: req.body.technicalDetails.networkSpec
        },
        videoBudget: {
            onlineBudget: req.body.videoBudget.onlineBudget,
            blurBudget: req.body.videoBudget.blurBudget,
            graphicsBudget: req.body.videoBudget.graphicsBudget,
            videoReviewBudget: req.body.videoBudget.videoReviewBudget
        },
        audioBudget: {
            voBudget: req.body.audioBudget.voBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.voBudget : 0,
            dialogBudget: req.body.audioBudget.dialogBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.dialogBudget : 0,
            soundEffectsBudget: req.body.audioBudget.soundEffectsBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.soundEffectsBudget : 0,
            soundDesignBudget: req.body.audioBudget.soundDesignBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.soundDesignBudget : 0,
            foleyBudget: req.body.audioBudget.foleyBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.foleyBudget : 0,
            audioMixBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioMixBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioMixBudget : 0,
            audioReviewBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioReviewBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioReviewBudget : 0,
            audioStemPrintBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioStemPrintBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioStemPrintBudget : 0,
            audioSecondaryBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioSecondaryBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioSecondaryBudget : 0
        }
    });

    try {
        // Save new project
        let project = await newProject.save();

        // Get new project ID to save into the client document
        let projectId = project._id;

        //Update client using new project _id
        let updatedClient = await Client.findByIdAndUpdate(clientId, {
            projects: projectId
        }, {
            new: true
        });

        console.log(INFORMATION);
        console.log(project);
        console.log(updatedClient);


        res.status(200).json(project);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Server Error',
            Error: error
        })
    }




});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it should work fine. We use mongoose.Type. ObjectId when we are defining a schema nor when we are saving its instance in database. you simply need to store the other model instance id as a reference which you can later use to retrieve the foregin object
replace 
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() 
by
    name_of_model: req. body. id

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Project = require('../../models/project.model');
const Client = require('../../models/client.model');


router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {

    let clientId = req.body.clientId;

    let newProject = new Project({
         // this below line has to change
        // _id field is auto increment in database
        model_name_id: req.body.id ,//model_name: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
        projectTitle: req.body.projectTitle,
        network: req.body.network,
        postSupervisor: {
            name: req.body.postSupervisor.name,
            email: req.body.postSupervisor.email ? req.body.postSupervisor.email : '',
            phone: req.body.postSupervisor.phone ? req.body.postSupervisor.phone : ''
        },
        seriesInformation: {
            services: req.body.seriesInformation.services,
            season: req.body.seriesInformation.season,
            numEps: req.body.seriesInformation.numEps,
            runtime: req.body.seriesInformation.runtime
        },
        technicalDetails: {
            frameRate: req.body.technicalDetails.frameRate,
            videoFormat: req.body.technicalDetails.videoFormat,
            videoFinishing: req.body.technicalDetails.videoFinishing,
            soundFormat: req.body.technicalDetails.soundFormat,
            sampleRate: req.body.technicalDetails.sampleRate,
            bitDepth: req.body.technicalDetails.bitDepth,
            audioLoudness: req.body.technicalDetails.audioLoudness,
            audioAlgorithm: req.body.technicalDetails.audioAlgorithm,
            audioPeakLimit: req.body.technicalDetails.audioPeakLimit,
            technicalSpec: req.body.technicalDetails.networkSpec
        },
        videoBudget: {
            onlineBudget: req.body.videoBudget.onlineBudget,
            blurBudget: req.body.videoBudget.blurBudget,
            graphicsBudget: req.body.videoBudget.graphicsBudget,
            videoReviewBudget: req.body.videoBudget.videoReviewBudget
        },
        audioBudget: {
            voBudget: req.body.audioBudget.voBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.voBudget : 0,
            dialogBudget: req.body.audioBudget.dialogBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.dialogBudget : 0,
            soundEffectsBudget: req.body.audioBudget.soundEffectsBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.soundEffectsBudget : 0,
            soundDesignBudget: req.body.audioBudget.soundDesignBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.soundDesignBudget : 0,
            foleyBudget: req.body.audioBudget.foleyBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.foleyBudget : 0,
            audioMixBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioMixBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioMixBudget : 0,
            audioReviewBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioReviewBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioReviewBudget : 0,
            audioStemPrintBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioStemPrintBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioStemPrintBudget : 0,
            audioSecondaryBudget: req.body.audioBudget.audioSecondaryBudget ? req.body.audioBudget.audioSecondaryBudget : 0
        }
    });

    try {
        // Save new project
        let project = await newProject.save();

        // Get new project ID to save into the client document
        let projectId = project._id;

        //Update client using new project _id
        let updatedClient = await Client.findByIdAndUpdate(clientId, {
            projects: projectId
        }, {
            new: true
        });

        console.log(INFORMATION);
        console.log(project);
        console.log(updatedClient);


        res.status(200).json(project);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Server Error',
            Error: error
        })
    }




});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite understanding this. I do understand that we're saving a ref to the ID. Can you write out some code to help, I'm not really seeing this thing you're talking about.

Comment: More specifically though, if I comment out all the code except for the newProject.save() and the res.status(200).json(newProject), I still get a 500 error. The data is actually saving in the database which is odd, but then an error throws. It'